# Shadow above candleflame

Tags: shadow

I had a oil burning candle in a dark room and noticed a small shadow on the ceiling directly above the flame.  Its as though the candle throws light outwards in every direction except straight up.  I'm curious as to why it does this. Perhaps its due to the conical shape of the flame?

Comment: Related: [The refraction through hot air around a candle flame](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/238789/the-refraction-through-hot-air-around-a-candle-flame) and [Shadow of fire doesn't exist](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/372117/shadow-of-fire-doesnt-exist)

Comment: Voting to leave open. It is not obvious to me that this is a duplicate. In the cited question the source of light is **not** the candle. In this question the source of light **is** the candle. Refraction might explain the dark spot, but it is not obvious how it works here. EG why is the spot dark not bright?