# Why does heat have a shadow?

Tags: thermodynamics, shadow

I just recalled the previous winter that I had stood in front of our heater to get warm. I then observed that the heat that was going up had a shadow on the wall behind the heater.

I suspect those were the shadow of the air molecules. But I can't prove.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/238789/123208

Comment: You should investigate the term "shadowgraph"

Comment: You should investigate the term "Schlieran". Veritasium made several videos on it. [How To See Air Currents](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tgOyU34D44) is one.